# PHP imap_open bind to IP

Tags: php, imap

Usually when using "imap_open" the connection is opening via the main IP address.

How I can bind another IP in my server to "imap_open"?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but the first argument to imap_open should contain a host name, e.g. `{localhost:143}INBOX"`. Instead of localhost, you can also provide an IP address. If that's not what you are asking, please clarify the question.

Comment: I mean, if my local server (not the IMAP server) has many IPs, how I can chose which IP the function imap_open will outgoing from it.

Comment: you cannot do that with php